# Are questions about crime statistics and the impact of law(s) allowed?

Tags: discussion

Are questions along the lines of

> what is the impact of law XYZ on crime/wellbeing?

allowed?

I think such questions are very interesting, but I am not sure if they're specific enough to law, or simply the impact of a law.

Answer (score 3):

I would vote to close the question which you asked as a call for opinions. It must be re-written so that it is actually a question about the law and which has a factual answer (one that is true or false). For example "Did Act 37 of 2012 reduce the {violent crime / unemployment} rate in Elbonia?". Questions about "wellbeing" are always too vague an opinion-laden to be on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

> Are questions about crime statistics and the impact of law(s) allowed?

Yes. Both aspects pertain to the [on-topic](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) item of "*Historical legal applications*". In fact, empirical research is showcased in several law journals. Two examples are about [Second Amendment Underenforcement](https://dlj.law.duke.edu/2018/10/second-amendent-7/) and the application of [Hypothesis Testing to Title VII Cases](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/230112044.pdf).

Although on topic, that type of questions is unlikely to elicit answers. That is in part because the combination of fields is quite narrow and of little-to-no interest even to us who have background in and/or exposure to both mathematics/statistics and law. Additionally, it seems to me that the percentage of legal issues on which empirical studies are available is relatively low.